# Android, play a sound the moment a view is visible on screen

Tags: android, image, audio

I am having trouble with audio in Android.  Here is the deal, I have a very simple splash screen.  My intention is once the screen loads it will play a very small audio file.

The problem is that a lot of the time, the audio will play before the splash screen actually appears.

Is there a way programmatically to verify that the screen has loaded? I do not want to add an unnecessary timer to make sure the sound doesn't play before it loads.  And I want the sound to play at the exact moment the screen appears.

Here is a snippet from my xml file:

```
<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/splash"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

splash is a .png image

And here is the onCreate code:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scarysplash);

```
mpPlaySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scream1);
mpPlaySound.start();
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you are not the only only one who has similar problem:)) There are couple of ways how to do that, the popular one is to implement **OnGlobalLayoutListener()**, e.g.:

```
    View yourView = ...;
                yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
                    {
                        // -----------------------------------------
                        //
                        // Callback method to be invoked when the 
                        // global layout state or the visibility 
                        // of views within the view tree changes 
                        //
                        // -----------------------------------------            
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() 
                        {

                                        // Remove view
                            View yourView = findViewById( R.id.yourId );

                            if ( yourView != null )
                            {
                                yourView .getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                            }
// PLAY SOUND
                        }
                    });
```

Petr

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  Thank you so much.  I will look in to this resolution.  I appreciate your time!